# how to get a variable from the url and pass it to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to get an id from the url and pass it to ajax. Is this possible? Because, when I try and get the id from the url and alert it out nothing appears. When I hard code the id it appears in the alert box.

http://example.co.uk/pass?id=1

ajax.js

```
$.get("pass.php", function(data){
  alert("Data: " + data);
});
```

pass.php

```
<?php

echo $data = $_GET['id'];

?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="" src="ajax.js"></script>
```

Comment: You need to pass http parameters to `$.get`. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your html head

```
<script>
   var id = <?php echo $_GET['id'] ?>;
</script>
```

and in ajax.js

```
 $.get("pass.php?id="+id, function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
  });
```

or

```
$.get("pass.php , {id : id} , function(data){
        alert("Data: " + data);
});
```